# Sed to replace text that comes after match

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I was working it with `awk`, and keying on `$1` `$2` fields, but `awk` would act differently depending on whether the FieldSeperator (`$match`) starts the line, or had a blank before it, or didn't have a blank before it.

I'm thinking that `sed` is my best choice for this particular task, but need some help.  I thought that I would be able to get this with a few simple searches, and although I've seen plenty of examples to replace the entire line, I haven't been able to find what I need to do below.  I would appreciate if someone is able to help me out.

I want to specify a variable (`$match`) that is set to the match I want to find (`password=`).  This will actually be in a batch script where I will loop through various patterns.

I want to print:

- only lines containing the match.  Ignore lines that do not have the match.
- print up to and including the 1st match value on the line
- if there is any value after the match, replace it with `masked`
- if there is nothing after the match, print line as is (or replace with `empty`)
- case insensitive search for the match.

**infile.txt**

```
dummy line  
mypassword=123  
PASSWORD=1234  
secret password=2345  2ndpassword=99485  
password=  
nothing to see move along
end of file
```

**Desired Output**

```
mypassword=masked  
PASSWORD=masked  
secret password=masked  
password=
```

Comment: If you say "if there is nothing after the match", does that include whitespace-only after the match, or only lines that end immediately after the `=`?

Comment: "_`awk` would act differently depending on whether the FieldSeperator (`$match`) starts the line, or had a blank before it, or didn't have a blank before it._" you can write an `FS` expression that handles this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -n '/password=/I{/=[[:alnum:]]/{s/\([^=]*=\).*/\1masked/};p}' input_file
mypassword=masked
PASSWORD=masked
secret password=masked
password=
```

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
$ sed -nE '/(password|PASSWORD)=/{s/=.+/=masked/;p;}' infile.txt
mypassword=masked
PASSWORD=masked
secret password=masked
password=
```

- match `password=` or `PASSWORD=`
- substitute any non-empty sequence of characters after `=`
- print the result

With GNU sed, you can simplify the case-insensitive match using the `I` modifier:

```
sed -nE '/password=/I{s/=.+/=masked/;p;}' infile.txt
```

Comment: This would change `file=password=` into `file=masked`, which may be unintentional.

Answer (score 1):

In "defense" of `awk`, and assuming your `awk` understands the `IGNORECASE` internal flag and POSIX character classes (this will probably limit it to GNU Awk), the following should do:

```
awk -v pat="$match" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;w=length(pat)} i=index($0,pat) {printf "%s%s%s",substr($0,1,i+w-1),substr($0,i+w)~/^[[:space:]]*$/ ? "" : "masked",ORS}' infile.txt
```

This will import the shell variable `$match` into the `awk` variable `pat`. In the `BEGIN` section, the `IGNORECASE` flag will be set to instruct `awk` to ignore case in matches.

It will only process lines where the `index()` function can successfully locate the search pattern (I chose to do a literal string match instead of a RegEx match to guard against characters with special meaning in your `$match` variable - use the `match()` function if a RegEx search is wanted instead). In this case it will print the line from the beginning up to and including the pattern, followed by the word `masked` unless the remainder of the line only consists of whitespace.

---

**A more portable variant** will use the `tolower()` function to transform the line to lower-case before performing the `index()` search (so, make sure the `$match` variable contains an all-lowercase search string), and doesn't make use of POSIX character classes:

```
awk -v pat="$match" 'BEGIN{w=length(pat)} i=index(tolower($0),pat) {printf "%s%s%s",substr($0,1,i+w-1),substr($0,i+w)~/^[ \t]*$/ ? "" : "masked",ORS}' infile.txt
```

This should work with all variants of `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to do it with `sed`, but `perl -p` works fine.

```
grep -i "$MATCH" "file.txt" | perl -p -e "s/(?<=$MATCH\S).*/masked/i"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed with its `/I` modifier for case insensitivity.

```bsh
##> ensure $match is pluggable
## on the kha of a s/// and/or
## /../
match='password='
match_lhs=$(printf '%s\n' "$match" | sed -e 's:[*[$.\^/]:\\&:g')

sed -n "
  /$match_lhs\$/Ip
  s/\($match_lhs\)..*/\1MASKED/Ip
" infile.txt

mypassword=MASKED
PASSWORD=MASKED
secret password=MASKED
password=
```